# Xamarin Forms Shell Overlay

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need some advice. I'm trying to create my own shell render [ShellOverlay](https://github.com/ORRNY66/ShellOverLayTest) that fills the entire display space, see the picture this works in Android10 but it doesn't work in Android 11.

Someone would know where the mistake might be.

Here in the picture, the ShellOverlay content is filled across the entire screen. The content is both under the StatusBar and under the NavigationBar

Android 10:

[image]

Android 11:
The contents of ShellOverlay do not overlap via the StatusBar

[image]

MainActivity.cs

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
 {
     Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
     Window?.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits, WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
 }
```

ShellOverlay renderers

```
public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    public CustomShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override IShellItemRenderer CreateShellItemRenderer(ShellItem shellItem)
    {
        return new CustomShellItemRenderer(this);
    }
   
}

public class CustomShellItemRenderer : ShellItemRenderer
{
    FrameLayout shellOverlay;
    View outerlayout;
    BottomNavigationView bottomView;
    IVisualElementRenderer viewRenderer;

    public CustomShellItemRenderer(IShellContext shellContext) : base(shellContext)
    {
    }

    public override Android.Views.View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        outerlayout = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        bottomView = outerlayout.FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottomtab_tabbar);
        shellOverlay = outerlayout.FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.bottomtab_tabbar_container);

        if (ShellItem is ShellOverlay overlay && overlay.Content != null)
            SetupOverlay();

        return outerlayout;
    }

    private void SetupOverlay()
    {
        var overlay = (ShellOverlay)ShellItem;

        bottomView.Measure((int)MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified, (int)MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified);

        outerlayout.Measure((int)MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified, (int)MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified);

        shellOverlay.RemoveAllViews();
        shellOverlay.AddView(ConvertFormsToNative(overlay.Content,
            new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(0, 0, Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width / Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density, Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height / Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density)));
    }

    public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        SetupOverlay();
    }

    private View ConvertFormsToNative(Xamarin.Forms.View view, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle size)
    {
        viewRenderer = Platform.CreateRendererWithContext(view, Context);
        var viewGroup = viewRenderer.View;
        viewRenderer.Tracker.UpdateLayout();

        if (view.HeightRequest > 0)
            size.Height = view.HeightRequest;

        var layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int)(size.Width * Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density), (int)(size.Height * Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density));
        viewGroup.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        view.Layout(size);
        viewGroup.Layout(0, 0, (int)view.Width, (int)view.Height);
        return viewGroup;
    }
}
```

layout/ BottomTabLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomtab.navarea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView 
        android:id="@+id/bottomtab.tabbar"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomtab.tabbar.container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
    
</FrameLayout>
```

Control ShellOverlay

```
public class ShellOverlay : ShellItem
{
    public View Content { get; set; }
}
```

AppShell.xaml

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:shellOverlay="clr-namespace:ShellOverLayTest.Views.Controls.ShellOverlay;assembly=ShellOverLayTest"
   Title="ShellOverLayTest"
   x:Class="ShellOverLayTest.AppShell"
   Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
   Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"
   Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

<shellOverlay:ShellOverlay x:Name="Overlay">
    <shellOverlay:ShellOverlay.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="GridRoot"  
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
              BackgroundColor="Red">

        </Grid>
    </shellOverlay:ShellOverlay.Content>
</shellOverlay:ShellOverlay>
```

AppShell.cs

```
 public AppShell()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    Overlay.Items.Add(new ShellContent { Route = nameof(MainPage), ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MainPage)) });
 }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: I checked the same code with yours. It works on my side to fill the full screen. Please check my screenshot. https://imgur.com/KYgA2MT Could you provide more details for to reproduce?

Comment: It is true that it works on the emulator. I tested it on a physical Realme GT 5G phone with UI 2.0 and also on a Samsung Galaxy S21 5G. In the XF Shell on both phones, the page content was not displayed in full screen. I also tried it with the classic Shell, where the page was not displayed on the entire display and then with a blank window, where the content of the page was already displayed on the entire display, so I think that the error will be somewhere in the XF Shell. That's why I created a thread on XF https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14716

Comment: I do not have the specific device to recheck. Let's follow the `#14716` on GitHub.